# zimbra user account creation using SOAP/REST

Tags: zimbra

I want to create a Zimbra account when ever user signup in my application.
is there any SOAP/REST calls for doing this job in Zimbra.

Please let me know if there are any other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SOAP account creation request should look like that :

```
<CreateAccountRequest name="{account-name}" password="{account-password}"> ## CreateAccountRequest
    (<a n="{key}" /> ## Attr)*
</CreateAccountRequest>
```

`name` contains the full Zimbra account name : `uid@domain.com`.

If you don't specifiy a `password`, the user won't be able to log in. (The password can be set later anyways).

`a` tag allows you to send some optionals attributes.

**Example :**

```
<CreateAccountRequest xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
    <name>username@domain.com</name>
    <password>foobar</password>
    <a n="givenName">John</a>
    <a n="sn">Doe</a>
    <a n="displayName">John Doe</a>
    <a n="zimbraCOSId">The CoS id comes here.</a>
</CreateAccountRequest>
```

Documentation :
[Zimbra SOAP requests](https://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.6.0/api-reference/index.html)

Comment: is there any Rest url for creating new user

Comment: Nope, there is not. Here some documentation : (http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_REST_API_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create accounts and domains in my NodeJS app, so I implemented a small nodeJS library (zimbra-client) https://github.com/grishick/zimbra-client for that.

Example of creating an account:

```
zimbra = require("zimbra-client");
zimbra.getAuthToken("localhost", "admin", "test123",
    function(err, authToken) {
        if(err != null) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        zimbra.createAccount("localhost",{sn:"Solovyev",givenName:"Greg",displayName:"Greg Solovyev",password:"test123",name:"greg@example.com"},authToken,
            function(err1,accountObj) {
                if(err1 != null) {
                    if(err1.code == "account.ACCOUNT_EXISTS") {
                        console.log("an account with this name already exists");
                    } else {
                        console.log(err1.message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("new account ID" + accountObj.id);
                }
            }
        );
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about any other ways.
There is one more way, from command line on zimbra server.

```
zmprov ca user@example.com somepassword
```

If you can run your app on the same box where zimra is running then you can use this interface.